# PHP (More SQL (MySQL/MariaDB)) - May I (the user) create a schema

Tags: php, mysql, sql, mariadb

Is there a way to check if one /may/ create a schema without creating a schema and checking for a failure? I've looked at `SHOW PRIVILEGES` but that shows "ALL" (for root) and tends to apply to a selected schema only.

I've been searching but most results are about permissions in a schema (because schema is one of my search terms)

I've mentioned I'm using PHP - I don't want to, I have to - in the case that someone wants to show me a function that parses output to deduce that one may create a schema.

Please note I do not want to (I do but I know how) to see if a schema exists, I want to know if I may create one WITHOUT actually doing it and seeing if it fails.

Answer (score -1):

```
show grants for 'username'@'host';
+--------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| Grants for openout@localhost                                                                                    |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
| GRANT USAGE ON *.* TO 'username'@'host' IDENTIFIED BY PASSWORD '*7041D3FA70F2EA166023420014A033ECA410EAB2' |
| GRANT SELECT, INSERT, UPDATE, DELETE, CREATE, DROP, INDEX, ALTER ON `adatabase`.* TO 'username'@'host'      |
+----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------+
2 rows in set (0.00 sec)
```

The problem is that it's a bit fussy about what's in the host field and how it's interpreted -  and the output is tricky to parse - might be simpler to look at the user, mysql and database tables in the mysql schema.

Comment: Those apply to tables on a schema, I want to know if CREATE SCHEMA or CREATE DATABASE (synonyms) will work without trying and failing if it doesn't work

Comment: BTW I downvoted because I think that's what I'm supposed to do when the answer doesn't apply, as you're a much older member than me, is that the right thing to do?

Comment: To allow a user to create a database then you need to GRANT CREATE ON *.* TO USER - this will be reported 'show grants'. See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/privileges-provided.html#priv_create

Comment: "The CREATE privilege enables creation of **new databases** and tables"

Comment: Then what distinguishes them?